# Speeding the Random process

Tags: java, android

I am practising on a simple Android Game where a round button is randomly placed on the screen when the user taps on it..
it works fine but i want to speedify the process of placing the button so that the game gets harder for user...

here is the Code I'm using -

```
public class GameWindow extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
static int score;
private Timer t;
private int TimeCounter = 29;
private boolean canMove = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    ////Remove title screen for activty.
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_window);
    moveButton();
    endonTimeOver();

}


public void endonTimeOver(){
    ////Activity timer for 60 seconds.

    final TextView timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seconds);

    t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        ////Set string to timer.
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    timer.setText(String.valueOf(TimeCounter)); // you can set it to a textView to show it to the user to see the time passing while he is writing.
                    TimeCounter = TimeCounter - 1;
                }
            });

        }
    }, 1000, 1000); // 1000 means start from 1 sec, and the second 1000 is do the loop each 1 sec.

    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask(){
        public void run() {
            GameWindow.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    startActivity(new Intent(GameWindow.this, Finished.class));
                }
            });
        }
    }, 30000);

}

////Move button.
private void moveButton()
{
    if(!canMove){ return; }

    runOnUiThread(
            new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {

                    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                    Point size = new Point();
                    display.getSize(size);
                    int width = size.x;
                    int height = size.y;

                    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
                    Random r = new Random();

                    int startX = width/2;
                    int startY = height/2;

                    if(score==0){
                        button.setX(startX);
                        button.setY(startY);
                    }

                    else {

                        int x = r.nextInt(width - 210);
                        int y = r.nextInt(height - 200);

                        button.setX(x);
                        button.setY(y);
                    }
                }
            }
    );

}




////Display score
public void displayScore(int score) {
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.buttonsound);
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.release();
        }

    });
    mp.start();

    score = score + 1;
    displayScore(score);
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case (R.id.button): {
           moveButton();
        }
    }

}

public static int getScore(){
    return score;
}}
```

Comment: why are you doing runOnUiThread ?

Comment: @yanivtwin what should i use then? actually I'm still learning so.. :) and besides, can we also speed up that?

Comment: i'm not sure without seeing some more code , can you post the mothod that calls moveButton() ?

Comment: @yanivtwin its in onCreate

Answer (score 1):

Use global variables for values that don't change:

- findViewById is slow
- Creating new Random every time is not necessary
- getting the window parameter every time is not necessary either

Comment: seems like you misunderstood, i want to increase the speed so that it gets difficult for user to react, find the new place where button is & tap :)

Comment: I higlighted the part of your code which makes everythin unneccarily slow. I thought that was your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be starting a new thread and telling it to runonui , this might be slowing you down , try this :

```
private void moveButton()
{
    if(!canMove){ return; }

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    Random r = new Random();

    int startX = width/2;
    int startY = height/2;

    if(score==0){
          button.setX(startX);
          button.setY(startY);
          }

    else {

       int x = r.nextInt(width - 210);
       int y = r.nextInt(height - 200);

       button.setX(x);
       button.setY(y);
       }
    }
```

the computation itself doesn't seem to heavy so no need for another thread , you can do it on the main thread , if you're calling from oncreate that means you're already on main thread , this might give you the answer if i understood the question , try it